# Using ASP to redirect user to new folder

Tags: forms, redirect

I know the heading sounds simple and I hope the answer is but I am new to ASP and cannot figure this one out. I am makeing a form which submits a user name to access.asp

```
<form name="input" action="access.asp" user="" method="get"> 
Username: <input name="user" type="text" />
<input value="Submit" type="submit" /></form>
```

What I want to actually achieve is when someone types a user name into the form and clicks submit, I want the form to move them to the next subdirectory with that user name.

```
ie. username=thomas  then they are redirected to a folder http://www.whatever.com/thomas/
ie. username=samantha   then they are redirected to a folder http://www.whatever.com/samantha/
```

and so forth. the folder would default for an index.html file or a 404 file if the entered username directory does not exist. I am trying not to create a database file unless this is required. I will only have 5-10 username directories when I am done.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, 
Erik

Comment: You're using old fashioned asp? Do you want to send a redirect using your response from the form, or do you want to just send them to a subdirectory that they type in the name of? If it's the latter, it can be done in just javascript.

Answer (score 0):

While this can be done in JavaScript. I'd continue to do it in ASP. Doing it on the server will allow you to check to make sure the username is valid, and if not then do something else.

With ASP.Net you'd want to use `Response.Redirect`

There are several Examples on different languages at Microsoft's MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Basicallys you'd just need

```
<% Response.Redirect "/" + Request.QueryString("username") %>
```